# Facebook Canvas redirect to /?fb_xd_fragment on IE7

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I created Facebook Canvas page with Facebook C# SDK 5.0.25. Unfortunately when I use IE7 then user is redirect to "/?fb_xd_fragment" page and as result he view blank page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=9777 and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/ for a possible workaround for that problem.

Specifically, you need to provide a channelUrl back to your page.

See also [this question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/2955012/facebook-javascript-sdk-fb-xd-fragment) which has some useful further links.